# How can I run WSL2 in Windows Emacs? M-x shell RET wsl RET doesn't output anything

Tags: emacs, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-11

How can I run WSL2 in Emacs? `M-x shell RET wsl RET` doesn't output anything.

This happens on my Windows 11 machine.

Tried it on macOS, Emacs told my macOS machine that its terminal is too dumb for WSL.

When I queried search engines about it, I mostly got results of people who want to use Emacs in WSL, but I want to run WSL in Emacs.

I think I need a buffer which is a PowerShell terminal.

Edit:

Tried to use `term` but when I try to set `powershell.exe` some child process is an invalid argument.

```
Spawning child process: Invalid argument
```

Edit:

Tried

```
(defun powershell (&optional buffer)
  "Launches a powershell in buffer *powershell* and switches to it."
  (interactive)
  (let ((buffer (or buffer "*powershell*"))
    (powershell-prog "c:\\windows\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe"))
    (make-comint-in-buffer "shell" "*powershell*" powershell-prog)
    (switch-to-buffer buffer)))
```

With this `M-x powershell` gives a PowerShell buffer, but it doesn't show things like the current directory, so stdout seems to be off.

Same with `M-x eshell RET powershell RET wsl`.

It works, but compared to the PowerShell terminal some things like `pwd` are missing.

I try it with PowerShell because it would be nice to have a fully functional PowerShell in Emacs and thus WSL would also work like in a PowerShell terminal.

Comment: what shell are you running from emacs on Windows? (check `M-:` `explicit-shell-file-name` or `shell-file-name` in emacs).  You can run wsl on macOS?  Emacs sets an environment variable `TERM=dumb`, but you can change that, eg `TERM=xterm-256color`, which may mess up some escape code interpretation etc

Comment: x86_64-w64-mingw32/cmdproxy.exe

Comment: Also, *"Tried it on macOS, Emacs told my macOS machine that its terminal is too dumb for wsl."* -- Can you elaborate on that statement?  WSL only runs on Windows - How were you trying to run it on macOS?

Answer (score 0):

There are several possibilities that I can think of at the moment.

*Short summaries:*

- Use single-line WSL commands
- Hobble along using Emacs standard-input/output in `shell` or `eshell`
- (Untested) Use [`fakecygpty`](https://github.com/d5884/fakecygpty) (from [the Emacs Wiki's Windows Integration page](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsMsWindowsIntegration#h5o-8)) to use `term`.
- Or simply run the Linux GUI version of Emacs under WSL.

---

*Explanation:*

The main problem with `shell` or `eshell` is that there is no real *terminal* associated with them.  Even after running `powershell.exe` or `cmd.exe` inside them, you can still see the limitations:

- You can backspace over the PowerShell or CMD prompt, because Emacs has no concept of character placement.
- You can't access `doskey`'s command history using <kbd>F7</kbd>
- Running `wsl tput lines` and `wsl tput cols` always returns 24x80, regardless of the screen size because there's no proper termcap for querying (it's just standard input/output to/from Emacs).
- `dir | more` doesn't work in CMD.
- `wsl -e stty -a` results in:

  ```
  stty: 'standard input': Inappropriate ioctl for device
  ```
- `wsl -e vi` results in:

  ```
  Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal
  Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal
  ```

All of these things should work correctly in a proper terminal.

Note that you can still run individual Linux commands using WSL inside the Emacs shell, as you can see in the examples above, using `wsl -e <command>`, as long as the command works on simple stdin/stdout.

You can even run multiple commands this way:

```
M-x term RET wsl -e bash -c "cd ~; ls -lah; cat /etc/os-release" RET
```

*Note:*  For some WSL commands, you may run into a bug in WSL's output being mangled.  The Windows terminals (`conhost` and Windows Terminal) handle this okay for the most part, but if you get garbled output from `wsl -l -v`, then:

- First, make sure you are running the latest version of WSL via `wsl --version`.  Currently, this is 1.0.0.  If not, `wsl --update` should bring you there, assuming you are on Windows 11 22H2.
- `M-x shell`
- Run `powershell`:

  ```
  $env:WSL_UTF8=1
  ```
- `wsl -l -v` should display correctly.

> Tried to use `term`

A good thought, but the problem here is that Emacs for Windows just doesn't ship with a terminal.  Under Linux, that would be the correct answer (see below).

---

*Possible solutions (expanded):*

My personal recommendation would be option (4) below, with (1) as my second choice ...

1. *Use single-line WSL commands*

   As mentioned above, you can use something like the following to run individual or multiple commands:

   ```
   M-x term RET wsl -e bash -c "cd ~; ls -lah; cat /etc/os-release" RET
   ```
2. *Hobble along using Emacs standard-input/output in `shell` or `eshell`*

   WSL will *work*, just very, very poorly in the `shell`.  You should be able to get an interactive (stdin/stdout) session running with:

   ```
   wsl -e bash --noprofile --norc -li
   ```

   There will be *no prompt* (at least, I haven't solved that problem yet).  But if you then run the `ls` command, it should actually return a result.  You can use Linux/WSL commands until you `exit` the WSL shell.
3. *(Untested) Use [`fakecygpty`](https://github.com/d5884/fakecygpty) (from [the Emacs Wiki's Windows Integration page](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsMsWindowsIntegration#h5o-8) to use `term`.*

   [`fakecygpty`](https://github.com/d5884/fakecygpty) is reported to provide a Cygwin terminal inside Emacs.  In theory, this terminal could then properly run WSL.
4. *Or simply run the Linux GUI version of Emacs under WSL.*

   Since you are running Windows 11, Emacs can run as a GUI app, and the look-and-feel will be very similar to the Windows version.  It's likely you can adapt your workflow to use *Windows* commands from inside the *Linux* version of Emacs rather than the other way around.

   When using the Linux version of Emacs inside WSL, you can use `term` or `ansi-term` to:

   - Run your normal WSL shell inside Emacs
   - Run PowerShell inside Emacs
   - Run CMD inside Emacs
   - Even run `vi` inside Emacs (since we all know Emacs is a great OS that just needs a great editor) ;-).
   - You can even run Windows applications that display their own GUI in a separate window.  E.g. `Show-Command` from PowerShell will open its own window.  Or `code .`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the first part of the question ("How can I run WSL2 in Emacs?") on Windows 10 I use this, the which worked with WSL1 and still works** with WSL2:

In your .emacs file add:

```
(defun my-bash-on-windows-shell ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((explicit-shell-file-name "C:/Windows/System32/bash.exe"))
    (shell)))

(global-set-key [f9] 'my-bash-on-windows-shell)
```

** the caveat is that after upgrading from WSL to WSL2 and from Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 22.04, the prompt $PS1 no longer displays, even a really simple one:

```
pwd
/mnt/c/temp

echo $PS1
foo

export PS1=bar

echo $PS1
bar

pwd
/mnt/c/temp
```

Unfortunately I don't knowwhich part of the upgrade process removed the display of $PS1.

If I run "C:/Windows/System32/bash.exe" separately, the $PS1 appears as normal.